# PHP laravel balde template

Tags: php, laravel-5

In laravel i try to create a registration page using blade template.

I am getting the reasult as

Registration Form

Name



Email



Password



Confirm Password

when i run the url i am getting the html tags not the registration form.The code in double braces not working.

Here is my register.blade.php

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>
      Registration Form
    </h1>
    {{Form::open(array('url' => 'register'))}}
    <p>
    Name
    </p>
    <p>{{Form::text('name')}}</p>
    <p>
    Email
    </p>
    <p>{{Form::text('email')}}</p>
    <p>
    Password
    </p>
    <p>{{Form::password('password')}}</p>
    <p>
    Confirm Password
    </p>
    <p>{{Form::password('cpassword')}}</p>
    <p>{{Form::submit('Save')}}</p>
    {{Form::close()}}
</body>
</html>
```

RegisterController.php

```
<?php

namespace myproject\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use myproject\Http\Requests;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
   function registerform(){
     return view('new_register');
   }
}
```

and routes.php

```
Route::get('registerform','RegisterController@registerform');
```

Why i am getting result like this?

Answer (score 0):

try using `{!! Form::text('name') !!}`

if you using laravel 5, dont forget to add this https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html